# Spring @NotNull validation constraint for a list of objects is not showing the required element name

Tags: java, validation, constraints, notnull

I am using the `@NotNull` annotation in my DTO to validate that some field mustn't be empty.

Just like this:

```
@NotEmpty
private String exampleField;

And I am getting the next error message:

{
"error": {
    "errorCode": "400",
    "message": "[must not be empty]",
    "id": "249ac058-dde9-497f-8a33-66730a4acb6a",
    "time": 1569366486479
},
"status": 400
}
```

The issue is that I am not getting the element name in the error response. I think that it is because in this request I have a list of my DTO. Just like this:

```
List<ChildDTO> child)
```

Because in another service with only one object in the requestBody Just Like this:

```
ChildDTO child
```

I have the response:

```
{
    "errorCode": "400",
    "message": "{exampleField=[must not be empty]}",
    "id": "4f6add3d-ed47-4b4c-b5a7-90c740407aae",
    "time": 1569366693073
}
```

I think that when I am sending a list of objects and one of these fields has this validation, something is happening and the element name is lost in the final message.

This are the methos which use the DTO:

```
@PostMapping(CHILD_PATH)
@Validated(OnCreationRequest.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ChildDTO register(@RequestBody @Valid ChildDTO CHILD) {
    return CHILDService.saveCHILD(CHILD);
}

@PostMapping(CHILD_REGISTER_PATH_LIST)
@Validated(OnCreationRequest.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public boolean registerAll(@RequestBody @Valid List<ChildDTO> CHILDs) {
    return CHILDService.saveAllCHILDs(CHILDs);
}
```

The problem is in the second one, because I have a list of:

```
List<ChildDTO> CHILDs
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you might need ti show more code and also are you specifying message in annotation `@NotNull(message="Account id can not be null")`?

Comment: @Deadpool I had updated the code, what you said before worked but the message is not complete. I mean I only see the "Account id can not be " message.

Answer (score 0):

Create another class as `Children` and declare the `List<ChildDTO>` as `@NotNull`.

```
class Children {

    @NotNull
    private List<ChildDTO> children;

    /**
     * getters & setters
     */
}
```

Update your controller function with `Children` class.

```
@PostMapping(CHILD_REGISTER_PATH_LIST)
@Validated(OnCreationRequest.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public boolean registerAll(@RequestBody @Valid Children children) {
    return CHILDService.saveAllCHILDs(children);
}
```